# Не удается переход на другой диск в cmd

Tags: windows, cmd

я пишу команду
C:\Users\Q>cd D:/
но нечего не происходит

Comment: После `cd D:/` напишите `D:/`

Comment: Либо, в `cd` добавьте опцию `/d`: `cd /d D:/`, чтобы сразу был переход